# How to store timestamp with timezone

Tags: oracle, symfony

I am trying to store a timestamp with timezone into my oracle db.

I have for example this code:

```
$deadline = new \DateTime('2018-11-07 13:33', new \DateTimeZone("EUROPE/BERLIN"));
$control->setDeadline($deadline);
```

and the result stored in my oracle db is this one: 
**07.11.18 13:33:00.000000000 +01:00**

but my goal is to to store the timestamp with this format: **07.11.18 13:33:00.000000000 EUROPE/BERLIN**

if I run this query the value is correctly saved with the desired format:

```
update my_table
set deadline = TIMESTAMP '2018-11-07 09:00:00 EUROPE/BERLIN'
```

What I am doing wrong? What is the correct way to format the timestamp to obtain the desired result with symfony?

Comment: Are you sure? Please verify with `to_char(deadline, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss TZR')`. Perhaps synfony transforms `Europe/Berlin` to `+01:00` - which would be a bug of course.

Comment: HI @WernfriedDomscheit, yes your query returns 2018-11-07 13:33:00 +01:00

Answer (score 1):

Looks like synfony transforms `Europe/Berlin` to `+01:00` - which would be a bug.

As workaround you could do following:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin';
```

and then insert the value without any time zone, i.e.

```
$deadline = new \DateTime('2018-11-07 13:33');
$control->setDeadline($deadline);
```

If you insert a timestamp into a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column and you don't provide any time zone information then Oracle defaults the time zone to your current `SESSIONTIMEZONE` which you set before.

You can set your `SESSIONTIMEZONE` also by Environment Variable `ORA_SDTZ` or in your Registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_{ORACLE_HOME Name}\ORA_SDTZ`, resp. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{ORACLE_HOME Name}\ORA_SDTZ`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this is not ok because I need to work with different timezones and I need to store different timezones in my db

Comment: Then maybe you can work with [FROM_TZ](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions077.htm#SQLRF00644) where you provide the time zone as plain string.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try to implement a solution with FROM_TZ